# Is there an XML Form Generator out there in .NET?

Tags: c#, xml, forms, generator

Is there any XML based form generator framework/library written in .NET? Basically, we want to be able to define the fields, datatype, controls, defaults, mandatory validations etc in an xml file and load a web page that will render a data entry form. This will include fields that can repeat n number of times in the form. (For example ingredients can repeat n number of times in a recipe database, or multiple addresses in a contact database) Data entry from this dynamic form will be saved in an XML output file.

I am trying to determine if I need to build this from scratch or if someone has invented a reusable wheel, so to speak.

Thanks for your help

MS

Comment: @Steven indeed; or alternatively, deserialization into an object model, and any view-engine such as "razor", which is frankly a bit more convenient (having worked a lot with both)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Let's be honest: XSLT sucks big time.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at XForms.

As a technology it doesnt seem to have caught on. The idea was that browsers supported it natively, but not many do today.

That said, there seem to be plenty of server side and even javascript libraries that are able to render xforms into traditional forms input.

- Good starting point [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms)
- a .net implementation (havent used it so can't say whether it is good) [here](http://mvcxforms.codeplex.com/)
- w3c wiki (lots of implementations) [here](http://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_Implementations)

Comment: You are right, there isn't much on XForm out there. I was looking primarily for a data driven Form Builder and I was hoping there would be something out there in XML that does the job. I am now expanding my search for any kind of form builder/generator in C#.